# Built-in monitor not working anymore after security and hardware update

Tags: updates, multiple-monitors

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and yesterday I was asked to install a new security and hardware update. I defered the update until this morning. After installing, I defered rebooting for a couple of minutes, because I was working on something. When I finally rebooted, the built-in display of the laptop stoped to work.

Not physically, of course. The boot menu as well as the splash screen are shown on it while booting, as usual. But as soon as the desktop comes up, the display goes black. The external monitor works without trouble, but even if I turn the external off in settings, and unplug the cable from the laptop, the built-in display remains black. Same when rebooting the laptop with only the built-in turned on and no other monitor connected. The display goes to black as soon as the desktop comes up. My laptop has essentially turned into a stationary workstation requiring an external monitor.

The display is recognised correctly by system settings, the resolution is recognised correctly, and I can even move the mouse out of the external monitor... Everything seems fine, except the darn thing only shows black.

I'm experiencing this problem on an hp ZBook. Has anybody had similar issues with this update, or in the past?

Some news, though not good:
tty apears on the built-in display as expected.
reverting to an older driver set brings the desktop back to the built-in display, but does not recognise an external display.
Installing newest NVIDIA binaries brings me back to status quo.

This is getting really annoying, as working on one screen reduces my efficiency, and right now the necessary time to set the machine up again from scratch is not justifiable, especially if I don't know whether that would actually solve the problem.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: Huh, this is strange... If I place the built-in display to the right in the settings, it still doesn't work, but I can then scroll the desktop over to the right on the external screen.  Todays update hasn't fixed anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going crazy here...

The situation fixed itself after the laptop went into standby over lunch. When coming back from standby the display configuration had completely changed (the displays were now mirrored, something I had previously tried but with just as little effect as everything else), and the image was on both screens. I could then reset the configuration, and it works. This wouldn't be half as baffling if half a dozen reboots since the problem started would have shown any effect.

I have no idea what happened, but hey, it's working again.

Comment: ...aaaand the display is gone again after reboot. It comes back when I suspend the system and then go back in. What on earth did they *do* in this update?

Comment: ...And it's broken again. It's like every reboot holds new surprises. Sometimes the mouse cursor on screen doesn't even match the position it really is in. Sometimes I get the image of both monitors on one, on top of each other and offset in one axis. Sometimes when I suspend and log on again the whole settings just changed apparently randomly, and sometimes the set settings do not reflect what is actually happening on the screens. All this after running this very setup for a year without any hickups. This is ridiculous!